# Relation between tables in different databases using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

is there any way to add a relation between 2 tables in different databases ?

For example:

```
db1.dbo.table1 field id = db2.dbo.table2 field id
```

the nearest thing that i´m looking for is something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RELATIONAL on IDCLIENT
FOR INSERT
As
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) = 1
      INSERT INTO db2.dbo.table2(ID) 
          SELECT ID FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [synonym](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/) for the other table in another db, and then you can reference it by its synonym name.

Comment: Thank you RedFilter, it clarified everything !